# Saved document doesn't inform user about no-saving the information

Tags: filesystem, libreoffice, thunderbird

I supported a person who received a .doc in Thunderbird as an email attachment, opened it, filled in a form and saved it. But the user couldn't find it anywhere.

Thing is that is was saved in /tmp . After reboot it was gone. Thunderbird however allow to save the changes there. 
What I would expect from Thunderbird, Libreoffice or Ubuntu to offer the user to save the doc after opened from an email as attachment but only with the save as option and then go automatically into the home directory.

My question is now: Where do I report such a bug?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming it's Thunderbird that should detect changes were made and ask to copy elsewhere: [Mozilla's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi)
- Assuming LibreOffice should detect that a temporary directory is being used: [LibreOffice's Bugzilla](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi)